# Add columns to two tables using Alter sqlite

Tags: java, php, android, sqlite

I am trying to do an update on my android app. I have a building database that is copied if the app is installed first Time. assuming that user might have stored some values in the table.

I want to release a new update in which I want to alter the database to add few more columns in diff tables

E.g I have two tables, A and B i want to add a row xx in both.

If I do

```
 db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE TTFindings ADD COLUMN imagePath STRING");
 db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE TTValues ADD COLUMN imagePath STRING");
```

I think we can't alter table two times that is giving error? `Can't access Read only database`
How can I make a query to alter two tables atonce?

Comment: Can't access Read Only database

Comment: Where do you get the `db` object from?

Answer (score 0):

The supported way of upgrading your database is through the use of SQLiteOpenHelper's onUpgrade method.   You shouldn't try to do this directly through your own code.

Please see my response to a similar question here.  If it helps, please +1!

[how do i create the database in my android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25950224/how-do-i-create-the-database-in-my-android-app/25950496#25950496)

Answer (score 0):

use this code.i hope this helps

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
          if (newVersion > oldVersion) 
{

    db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE TTFindings ADD COLUMN imagePath STRING");
     db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE TTValues ADD COLUMN imagePath STRING");
}

}
```